# How to add npm package to cocos creator project?

Tags: typescript, npm, cocoscreator

I have a problem with adding npm package to Cocos Creator v3.8 project.

I want to add that [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) because it can be really usefull to read google sheets data in editor time for game configuring.

In process of installation I followed next steps:

1)Installed the package in projects root folder, using `npm install --save typescript ts-node @types/node googleapis` command in command prompt.

2)After that, Ive been able to use package code inside of my project scripts - VS Code automatically added `import { google } from 'googleapis';` after `const auth = new google.auth.JWT` call. But editor started to log an error:
`Error: Unresolved specifier ./lib/mappingTable.json`
And my script was not working.

3)After googling some info about npm packages problems, I found an advice in [that thread on cocos forum](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos-creator-v3-0-and-npm-modules/52742/10) about import maps. So I created import-map.json file with next syntax:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "googleapis": "./node_modules/googleapis/build/src/"
  }
}
```

and reffered to it in Project Settings/Scripting tab.
But now editor logging

`[Scene] Error: Error: Directory import is not supported`

`[Scene] Missing class: ee756oFCtRKa4sg3jxG8FrD`

`[Scene] Missing class: 06063xe/bRFu6qv9Dplmdk0`

and my scripts still dont work.

I`m new in Cocos creator and typescript development - there are a lot of things I may not understand properly. What should I do to make that npm package run properly for my game scripts?